# How can I customize cards positioning Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I need some help because I can't find a way to customize the way bootstrap cards are displayed on the screen.
For example, when the screen width is 860 I would like for it to only load 2 cards instead of 3 and when the width is like 600 it to load 2 but smaller so they fit in the same row! Is there any way I can achieve this result?

```css
/* Title */
#cc{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 180px;
}

#Slogan{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.text-gray-soft{
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#btn{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Newest TAB */
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #nn{
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .line1{
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .card{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #nn{
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  .line1{
    margin-right: 200px;
  }
  .card{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1300px) {
  #nn{
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 300px;
  }
  .line1{
    margin-right: 300px;
  }
  .card{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1800px) {
  #nn{
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 400px;
  }
  .line1{
    margin-right: 400px;
  }
  .card{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/index.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BoostTemplates</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="cointainer" id="cc">
      <h1 class="display-1 text-bold" id="Slogan">Make <br>anything</h1>
      <h5 class="text-gray-soft">All the themes you need in one place.</h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" id="btn" >SHOP</button>
    </div>
    <div class="cointainer" id="nn">
      <h4 class="display-5 NewestT">Newest</h4>
      <h6 class="text-gray-soft">Recently added to the shop</h6>
      <hr class="line1">
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="containerpart">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="static/images/BS_Dashboard-400x300.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Dashboard</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Clean and simple dashboard and admin interface.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="static/images/BS_Dashboard-400x300.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Dashboard</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Clean and simple dashboard and admin interface.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="static/images/BS_Dashboard-400x300.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Dashboard</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Clean and simple dashboard and admin interface.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Read the bootstrap documentation. It already have such responsive layout solutions https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: @GramThanos I managed to make them stay in the center of the page but i still didnt find a way to make it only show on or two cards in difrent screen width or if possible when its min 500px and max 900px make it display the cards in a courosel like this shows: https://codepen.io/kreigd/pen/ybYNoN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you define a `row` and inside it, you define your `col`s.

Imagine each row to be divided into 12 sections. You then assign on each `col` how many of these sections you want it to cover, on each screen size category.

Thus if you want on small screens to have 2 cards per row and on bigger screens 3 per row, you set `col-6 col-md-4`, this means on Extra small screens (smaller than 576px) cover 6 out of 12 (1/2), while on small screens or bigger (greater or equal to 576px) cover 4 out of 12 (1/3).

Example code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
            Card 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
            Card 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
            Card 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
            Card 4
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
            Card 5
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
            Card 6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Based on your code

```css
/* Title */
#cc{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 180px;
}

#Slogan{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.text-gray-soft{
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#btn{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Newest TAB */
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #nn{
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .line1{
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .card{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #nn{
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  .line1{
    margin-right: 200px;
  }
  .card{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1300px) {
  #nn{
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 300px;
  }
  .line1{
    margin-right: 300px;
  }
  .card{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1800px) {
  #nn{
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 400px;
  }
  .line1{
    margin-right: 400px;
  }
  .card{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/index.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BoostTemplates</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="cointainer" id="cc">
      <h1 class="display-1 text-bold" id="Slogan">Make <br>anything</h1>
      <h5 class="text-gray-soft">All the themes you need in one place.</h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" id="btn" >SHOP</button>
    </div>
    <div class="cointainer" id="nn">
      <h4 class="display-5 NewestT">Newest</h4>
      <h6 class="text-gray-soft">Recently added to the shop</h6>
      <hr class="line1">
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="containerpart">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="static/images/BS_Dashboard-400x300.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Dashboard</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Clean and simple dashboard and admin interface.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="static/images/BS_Dashboard-400x300.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Dashboard</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Clean and simple dashboard and admin interface.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="static/images/BS_Dashboard-400x300.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Dashboard</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Clean and simple dashboard and admin interface.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I did what you told and it worked fine but now the cards are all together:

Comment: It works just fine for me, based on your code. (I added it on my answer)

Comment: for me it appears that all of them when min 500px are all on top of each other

Comment: If you are talking about the overlapping, that is because the does not fit. If I were you, I would remove the `width: 18rem;` (because it breaks the bootstrap responsiveness) and instead of `col-6 col-sm-4` like you asked, I would use `col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4` (1 per row for extra small screens, 2 for small screens, 3 for bigger screens).